# Login to magento back office will not work

Tags: admin-panel, admin-login, cpanel

Please help

website working fine.

The data file is not able to access admin panel for website itself.  Issue with the mapping so we still cannot access the websites back office in magento.

If anyone can help please

Comment: What do you mean by "data file is not able to access admin panel"?

Comment: We are unable to sign in on our admin panel to our back office

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The login to admin panel of magento you put the username then password then it goes to a page which says it’s not working and the website did not receive any data ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Have you checked Magento's log files under {project-folder}/var/log directory? Also check server's error log file for more clues.

Comment: Thank you but I don’t know how to do that

Comment: If you are unable to do that, you can hire a professional developer to check the issue for you and fix.

Comment: Without checking the error logs, it is hard to tell the solution.

Comment: Are you able to run Magento commands and do you have server's full access?